# The term not recognized powershell

Tags: function, powershell, import, module, runtime-error

In my script I declared the function and then called it out with `GetNewClosure` . The function is event handler for numerous number of buttons I created. When I am running it in ISE everything is fine but when i'm trying to run script  it shows me error: `"filling : The term 'filling' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At C:\Users\klima\Desktop\SYOP\KolkoiKrzyzyk.ps1:210 char:38
+             $Button[$i,$j].Add_Click({filling -a $i -b $j}.GetNewC ...
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (filling:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException` . The spelling is good and i declared the function before calling it out. I did my research and i know that "GetNewClosure" creates new module. Can anyone tell me how can I import this module? Below i present the code:

```
Function filling{
Param(
[int]
$a,
[int]
$b)

    if ($a -lt 9 -and $b -eq 0){ 
        if($Script:who -eq $true){
            $Button[$a,$b].Image=[System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$env:UserProfile\Deswhop\SYOP\kolko.jpg")
            $Script:P[$a]= "o" 
            Set-Variable who -Value $false -Scope Script
            }

        else{
            $Button[$a,$b].Image=[System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$env:UserProfile\Deswhop\SYOP\krzyzyk.jpg")
            $Script:P[$a]= "x" 
            Set-Variable who -Value $true -Scope Script
            }
    }
    if ($a -lt 9 -and $b -eq 1){
        if($Script:who -eq $true){
            $Button[$a,$b].Image=[System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$env:UserProfile\Deswhop\SYOP\kolko.jpg")
            $Script:P[($b*10 + $a) - 1]= "o" 
            Set-Variable who -Value $false -Scope Script
            }

        else{
            $Button[$a,$b].Image=[System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$env:UserProfile\Deswhop\SYOP\krzyzyk.jpg")
            $Script:P[($b*10 + $a) - 1]= "x" 
            Set-Variable who -Value $true -Scope Script
            }
    }
    if ($a -lt 9 -and $b -eq 2){
        if($Script:who -eq $true){
            $Button[$a,$b].Image=[System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$env:UserProfile\Deswhop\SYOP\kolko.jpg")
            $Script:P[($b*10 + $a) - 2]= "o" 
            Set-Variable who -Value $false -Scope Script
            }

        else{
            $Button[$a,$b].Image=[System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$env:UserProfile\Deswhop\SYOP\krzyzyk.jpg")
            $Script:P[($b*10 + $a) - 2]= "x" 
            Set-Variable who -Value $true -Scope Script
            }
    }

$Button[$a,$b].Enabled=$false
}
```

```
for([int]$i=0;$i -lt 9 ; $i++){
        for([int]$j=0;$j -lt 3 ; $j++){
            $Button[$i,$j].Add_Click({filling -a $i -b $j}.GetNewClosure()) 

    }
}
```

Comment: please add the FULL text of the error ... and a minimal code to produce the error ... to you Question. also, please wrap each in code formatting markers.

Comment: Sorry, I was writing it fast, i corrected everything to be readable

Comment: that does not look like the FULL text of the error message. it usually includes the line number and part of the code.

Comment: it shows error in this line: `$Button[$i,$j].Add_Click({filling -a $i -b $j}.GetNewClosure())`

Comment: thank you for the added info ... please post that in your Question & you post the FULL TEXT IN ONE PIECE, not broken into disconnected bits. you make it difficult to see the context when you break it up. [*grin*]

Comment: kool! the context helps. [*grin*] ///// your 1st block of code is not a proper function. where is the 1stpart of it - the `function FunctionNme` part? ///// also, where is the definition of `filling`?

Comment: it is right above the declaration of parameters I forgot to click Enter before typing code

Comment: excellent! things make more sense now. [*grin*] ///// what happens if you rename the function? erase the _entire_ `function fillling {` line and type in a new line - an entire new line with an entirely different name. perhaps something like `function Get-TestFilling {`. the type in - not copy & paste - the new function name where needed. ///// the reason i ask is that _sometimes_ copying things can result in non-standard characters becoming embedded in the text ... so try to remove & retype the possibly garbled text.

Comment: Same error appears

Comment: you will need to trace the commands - either with the trace cmdlets OR via the debugger. there is SOMETHING that is not in your description that is causing the problem ... but i have no idea how to discover what you have not noticed. [*grin*]

Comment: I suppose it could be problem with module created by `GetNewClosure()` but i have no idea how to get to it

Comment: Okay. Making function `filling` global was enough. Problem solved

Comment: ah! that means you left out how the script was organized. next time, you otta include all the info ... [*grin*] in any case, i am glad that you found a fix!